# inheritence/interface setting a class with multiple related classes as single instance

Tags: php, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

I have a data object, lets call it "user".

A "user" has multiple instances of data object "custom data fields"
A "user" has multiple instances of data object "attributes"

when I instantiate a user new user($id); i would also like to instatiate the related data

```
class user extends customDataFields, attributes {
// constructor returns a user object
}
```

user object looks like

```
user{
    // user data
    customFields{ 
        // customfield data
    }
    attributes {
        //  attribute data
    }
}
```

How do I set up the class inheritance/interface so that instantiating "user" instantiates the related data objects?

Comment: How many customDataField objects and attribute objects ought to be created when a user is created?

Comment: You can extend only one class in PHP! And the `user object looks like` code isnt real PHP code

Comment: You should read about ORM Databases (like http://propelorm.org/), to get a feeling for what you want to do in PHP.

Comment: If an object has multiple instances of another class, you don't do that with inheritance. The object needs a property that contains an array of the other class.